# How to politely tell someone they did not hit "reply to all" in an email?

Tags: communication, email

It happens sometimes that somebody (likely) meant to reply all in an email chain, but (likely) accidentally just replied to the last person that sent the email. What is a polite way to inform them of this/ask if they actually intended to reply all?

Comment: And you are confident they did not Reply with all moved to BCC?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

> Hi Bob - just so you're aware, seems like you haven't hit reply all there.

No need to dress it up any more than that.

Comment: Short and concise. It's not polite to waste people's time with a lengthy email that could have been one sentence or less.

Comment: Agreed. I'll often add something like "I can't count the number of times I've done the same thing" to ameliorate their embarrassment a bit. (Even though I like to think I'm pretty careful about this sort of thing...)

Comment: Okay but what if his name isn't Bob

Comment: @SombreroChicken You should of course call him (or her) Bob anyway, following my answer exactly, and not changing it in the slightest to fit the situation ;)

Comment: And be sure to sign off as berry120.

Comment: The Bob part is necessary because when people try to get too chummy you need to occasionally call them by the wrong name to let them know that you don't really care. Unless their name is Bob of course.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Hey Bob, you completely missed the point of this answer. The point is that it is polite to call everyone Bob.

Comment: Really subtle thing, but I would suggest a slight tweak so that the wording doesn't imply that you definitely know the person's intentions. Maybe "it seems like you meant to hit 'reply all' there but didn't?", because maybe they *didn't* mean to hit reply all, and some people get really bothered by having others presume/misunderstand their intent. In my experience it's relatively rare that this happens, and even more rare that they do anything worse than silently judge you worse as a person for it, but I don't really see a downside to using wording that doesn't do that by default.

Comment: What if Bob is your uncle?

Comment: @berry120 Maybe Bob is short for Kate.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb In which case you call them Michael.

Answer (score 62):

Be straightforward.

I'm assuming, in this case, you were the last sender and by clicking the "reply" button, you are the only one who got that email. Then, One way could be, reply to the email which was only sent to you and inform them about the mistake like

> *Hey, did you mean to reply-to-all?*

That should do just fine, no need to overthink it.

---

*Considering another case:*

Where you were not the last sender, you were missed in the email whereas, the intention was to have you (and others) in loop.

You may have received the update from someone else and upon *"investigation"* you discovered it was probably because of the mix up in "reply" vs. "reply all".

In that case, probably the best way out is to reply to the original thread and request for any update. If it was a genuine mistake from the sender, you should see the email they sent out previously to be forwarded to the entire recipient list pretty soon.

Comment: @Will Thanks for being that guy. :) (_Actually, me goes and sulks in a corner_)

Comment: @Will In C#, it is perfectly fine to use [`?.`](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/05/11/3-misused-of-operator-in-c-6/) (at some point) haha

Answer (score 25):

If you are *quite* confident they simply made a mistake, save them the time and effort of resending. Just reply-all yourself, and say something like

> Copying everyone else in on this message

Comment: Pretty much everybody does this after a year or two.  It's up to the sender to call "eyes only".

Comment: It may not be appropriate in some more formal threads were clear visibility of who wrote what is important - forwarded citation may be hidden, and email coming from wrong person may be ignored. In these sensitive cases, e.g. if the sender is your manager, and attention of someone higher in the chain is needed, asking the author to re-send the email correctly is safer. In usual, everyday cases - yeah, re-sending the message yourself is the simplest option.

Comment: Meanwhile, while you're "saving them the time and effort", the original sender has realized their mistake and already re-sent the e-mail to everyone, "helpfully" omitting you the second time around so you don't get duplicate messages. Now everyone *except* you has been spammed with the same message twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can say something polite like:

> It looks you intended this email for all of us, and I'm guessing you meant to hit Reply All?

To avoid problems like this, I would like to share a handy email habit that I learned about at a previous workplace. Here it is: when someone in the team adds new people in an email thread, they would start the email body with a sentence like this:

> [CC Bob Smith, Alice Jackson]

Because changes in the CC field are very easy to miss in most email interfaces, this would point out the change and indicate that the change was intentional.

Similarly, if someone removed people from the To: or CC: fields, they would start the email body with a sentence like this:

> [To Alex only]

Again, that points out the change to a reader who might have missed it, and indicates that the change was intentional.

If the people in your workplace are in the habit of using a system like this, it makes it obvious when somebody accidentally hits Reply instead of Reply All, and you can confidently add back missing email thread participants without needing to ask permission first.

Comment: While this sounds like it could be a positive change, how would you suggest the OP introduces it to, and gets buy in from, their team?

Comment: @PlayerOne Just start using it and see if the habit spreads. Nobody imposed it on me, I just picked this up. I don't want to stray too far from the original question so I don't think I should elaborate more in the answer post.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems some people didn't get the message, let's include them now.

That way you aren't blaming anyone. It's also useful when by mistake a certain individual gets taken out from the conversation and then you can say

> Just including XY in the conversation, it seems he didn't get some of the messages.

Again, not blaming anyone, even though a perceptive person will be able to see who made the mistake in the conversation chain.

Answer (score 0):

What I personally do, is if I think that the original respondents would benefit from the email, I either forward the email to them or reply to the email saying something like thanks and add the other intended recipients.

No need to do anything that can be taken negatively and there is a possibility that the respondent will understand that the others would have benefited from his email.